# TabPanel Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I am working with a Ext Js web with some TabPanels and some tabs, and I want to use some different JQuery on each tab, the problem is that if I attach some JQuery event it gets attached to all the tabs, because they are in the same HTML, thus I want to unbind all JQuery events before opening one tab and also bind the ones I want for it, having the events listening just when the corresponding tab it is opened.

For testing the events I attached the following listener to my tabPanel:

```
listeners:{
        beforetabchange : function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert("beforetabchange");
        },
        beforeshow : function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert("beforeshow");
        },
        activate : function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert("activate");
        },
        deactivate : function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert("deactivate");
        }   
  }
```

So I was expecting many pop ups, but the only one showed is the one corresponding to "beforetabchange" and it is only executed the first time that I open one tab... so there is something I do not get, for example: Should be shown the "activate" pop every time I open a tab? I was expecting so.

Comment: 1) Why in the world do you want to use ExtJS and jQuery **together**? ExtJS is way enough. 2) When you change tabs, the **TabPanel** fires the `beforetabchange` event, and the **individual panels** that get changed (not the TabPanel that contains them!) fire the `activate` and `deactivate` events, that makes sense.

Comment: @Drmitry Jquery provides a more comfortable access to the DOM than ExtJs

Comment: I would argue about the comfortable access but I think it's irrelevant in this case, because ExtJS is a VERY heavy library, and if you're using it you don't want to add jQuery on top of it just because you like it, it's a huge overkill.

Comment: I do not want to argue about why I need it, because it is hard to explain and it is off the topic so please, focus in the question.
Well the TabPanel fires the `beforetabchange` just the **first time** I open each tab, so for my objective is useless and with that name it does no make sense (for me at least)
About the `activate` and `deactivate` I do not get what you mean, do not know how to attach it correctly or fire it, If you could clarify it would be a great help.

Comment: @Javier the question cannot be answered with that lees information. And if I must I would say it has something to do with the parallel use of another DOM manipulating framework alongside ExtJS that causes changes ExtJS not recognized

Comment: Javier, **1)** I don't know why you get `beforetabchange` fired only once. I modified the live example in the docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel) and I get `beforetabchange` fired every time I switch tabs. **2)** You add `activate` and `deactivate` listeners on the child panels of your TabPanel. **3)** Please make it clearer where jQuery comes in in your code. Please provide a more complete example (jsFiddle preferrably).

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to understand what you want to do, but i have below code, Might be its help you.

```
items:[{
      xtype: 'tabpanel',
      activeTab: 0,
      items:[{
            title: 'tab1',
            id:'divtab1',
            autoHeight: true,
            items:[{
                  // your content here
            }]
      },{
            title: 'tab2',
            id:'divtab2',
            autoHeight: true,
            items:[{
                  // your content here
            }]
      },{
            title: 'tab3',
            id:'divtab3',
            autoHeight: true,
            items:[{
                  // your content here
            }]
      }],
      listeners: {
            'tabchange': function(tabPanel, tab){
                 if(tab.id=="divtab1")
                 {
                       function1();
                 }
                 else if(tab.id=="divtab2")
                 {
                       function2();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                       function3();
                 }
            }
       }

}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help guys.
Finally what I did was use the `activate` and `deactivate` events correctly, adding these listeners to each `Panel` created for the `TabPanel`, not directly in the TabPanel's listeners list as I was doing before.